# Is there a way to see a preview of all my video clips within Windows Explorer, just by hovering the mouse, like on YouTube?

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, windows-explorer, media-player

I like to know if there's a way, maybe a tool/software that extends Windows Explorer in order to allow me to see a rolling preview of video clips when I hover the mouse over them, just like I'm able to to on sites like YouTube, Dailymotion and several other websites.

In the web that seems like pretty standard nowadays. I can't afford a expensive video editing software that maybe would allow me to do that, and I use several softwares, so that could really speed up my process by allowing me to know which clip am I hovering.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does not do this natively.

There are a number of reasons why.  For example, the vast number of video file types and [codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec).  While Microsoft does support a wide variety, they can't, or don't choose to support everything.  They leave this up to third party programs.  Additionally, file size is an issue.  Hovering over a large video file, especially on a low power machine, means that Windows will attempt to load that file, rescale the image to a smaller size and scrub through the file.  This can take a lot of resources, not to mention some older or improperly created videos do not support scrubbing.

YouTube bypasses these issues by converting all uploaded videos to a one streaming format.  In addition to that, it creates multiple versions of that stream in different resolutions, one of which being the thumbnail.  When you hover the mouse over a YouTube thumbnail, it plays the thumbnail stream in a format your browser can natively play.

There *may* be third party software that does this, but I dont know of any.  Additionally, software recommendations are outside the scope of Superuser.

Comment: Thank you. That was really insightful. I'll maybe try to tackle this just for fun and try to build a small clip library manager that could do that for some specific file types.